# ComboBox Display system.data.datarowview vb.NET

Tags: vb.net

When I want to select a hotel name I want to assign each hotel name with number of room it has

```
sqlCmd1 = "Select ROID from Room"
        ad = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCmd1, cnn)
        ds = New DataSet
        ad.Fill(ds, "Room")
        For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            roomCB.Items.Add(row.Item(0))
        Next
```

This is the ComboBox for the hotel

```
 Private Sub hotelCB_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
                                           Handles hotelCB.SelectedIndexChanged    
        If (hotelCB.SelectedIndex = 0) Then
            sqlCmd1 = "Select ROID from Room"
            ad = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCmd1, cnn)
            ds = New DataSet
            ad.Fill(ds, "Room ID")
            roomCB.DataSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
        ElseIf (hotelCB.SelectedIndex = 1) Then
            sqlCmd1 = "Select ROID from Room where HotelID=" + 
                                                hotelCB.SelectedIndex.ToString()
            ad = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCmd1, cnn)
            ds = New DataSet
            ad.Fill(ds, "Room ID")
            roomCB.DataSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the actual problem or what error do you get?

Comment: cool. whats the problem?

Comment: @Banana: the problem is stated in the title: combobox displays `System.data.datarowview` instead of the ROID.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specifiy the `DisplayMember`:

```
roomCB.DisplayMember = "ROID";
roomCB.ValueMember = "ROID";
roomCB.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your ComboBox load logic to

```
    sqlCmd1 = "Select ROID from Room"
    ad = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCmd1, cnn)
    ds = New DataSet
    dt = New DataTable
    ad.Fill(ds, "Room")
    dt=ds.Tables(0)
    For i as integer=0 to dt.Rows.Count - 1
        roomCB.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(0))
    Next
```